# ¿Por qué obtengo HTTP 301 al tratar de instalar una gema de Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Hola al tratar de instalar una nueva gema de [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) me arroja el error HTTP 301.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

[image: Pantalla con error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se necesita actualizar [rubygems](/questions/tagged/rubygems) mediante `rubygems-update` de la siguiente manera:

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
```

En caso de no tenerlo instalado mandará error y el procedimiento es le siguiente:

1. Descargar desde https://rubygems.org/pages/download
2. Descomprimir y posicionarse en el directorio descomprimido
3. Instalar mediante el comando: `ruby setup.rb`

Se deberá de tener instalado por lo menos `Ruby 1.8.7`

Comment: Considero que seria mejor un mínimo de 1.9.x ya que los cambios entre 1.8.7 y 1.9.x son bastante grandes por lo que el código podría no funcionar correctamente.